# Visual Studio replace old code block with new code

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I want to replace all occurences of a certain `if` pattern with my new code.

For example these are the situations I want to find:

```
        if (builder == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));


if (builder == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

if(builder==null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    
if (builder == null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
}
    
if(builder==null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
    
if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

if(builder==null) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
}
```

and replace them with

```
ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);
```

What I tried is to use the "**Find and Replace**" build in function of Visual Studio and use a regex to match my search pattern:

```
if\s*\(\s*([^)]+)\s*==\s*null\s*\)\s*{?\s*throw\s*new\s*ArgumentNullException\s*\(\s*nameof\(\1\)\s*\);\s}?
```

The problem is, that this works in regex101, but not in Visual Studio.

Here is the regex101: https://regex101.com/r/usKBOk/1

Here is a screenshot of my search settings, trying to see if Visual Studio finds anything:
[image: Find in Files]

Comment: I see you posted the pattern (as text) that ends in `\s}?`, but the pattern in the screenshot (not fully visible) ends in `\s*}?`, are you sure you used the same pattern in VS as in regex101?

Comment: Just FYI: `\s*{?\s*` is bad, you must write it as `\s*(?:{\s*)?` to prevent redundant backtracking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for giving advice. The screenshot might be of me trying to fix the regex, but the regex in the question is the one I used.

Comment: Try escaping curly braces.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? Any of you tried this in Visual Studio or are you just trying the regex and wonder why am I even asking this? It's because it doesn't work in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Visual Studio regex in *Find and Replace* follows the same rules as Visual Studio Code, and the pattern will never match line breaks with `\s` or `[^()]` if there is no `\n` or `\r` in the pattern itself.

In these cases, I'd still suggest a fool-proof solution: **Add a `\r{0}` pattern at the start**.

So, in your case, you can use

```
\r{0}if\s*\(\s*([^)]+)\s*==\s*null\s*\)\s*{?\s*throw\s*new\s*ArgumentNullException\s*\(\s*nameof\(\1\)\s*\);\s*}?
```

**Alternative solutions**

- Add `\r` or `\n` inside the first positive or even negative(!) character class, e.g. `[^)]` => `[^)\n]` or `[^)\r]`. It is strange for common regex users, but it works in Visual Studio editor and Visual Studio Code. *It is not recommendable* since testing in online regex tools will not be consistent with the VS results.
- You may replace the first `\s*` with `[\s\r]*` (no need to repeat this with all other occurrences of `\s` in the pattern since the first one will automatically enable `[^)]` and `\s`, and `\p{Z}`, to match line breaks). This is *safe to use* since it is consistent with online regex testers.

*Demo screenshot*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected in Visual Studio.